# eBay API - Add Item - Can I set a listing to post at a time other than when the request is made?

Tags: api, ebay-api

Is there any way to make an AddItemRequest via the Trading API to queue the listing so that it posts at a specified datetime rather than as soon as the request is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the Item.ScheduleTime node. All you need to do is pass the time you want the listing to go live there.

[Item.ScheduleTime](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/additem.html#Request.Item.ScheduleTime)